# If $ \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) = \frac{4}{7} $ find $ \frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}+\frac{1}{\cos^2{2x}} + \frac{1}{\cos^2{3x}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) = \dfrac{4}{7} $  and $S=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2{x}}+\dfrac{1}{\cos^2{2x}} + \dfrac{1}{\cos^2{3x}} $ when $ S \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ then $ S = ? $

P.S. I have tried that , but failed many times. Because I suppose that $\cos(x) ,\cos(2x) , \cos(3x)$ be root of   $8\cos^{6}(x) -10\cos^{4}(x) + 3\cos^{2}(x) - \frac{4}{7} = 0 $

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: The problem really seems to be too interesting, unfortunately does not seem to be complete

Comment: $$8=7\cos2x(2\cos x\cos3x)=7\cos2x(\cos2x+\cos4x)=7\cos2x(\cos2x+2\cos^22x-1)$$

$$\iff14\cos^32x+7\cos^22x-7\cos2x-8=0$$

Comment: oh , thank you. But if I change $\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) = \frac{4}{7} $  to
$8cos^{6}(x) -10cos^{4}(x) + 3cos^{2}(x) - \frac{4}{7} = 0 $ and then solve as cubic equation . is it possible to solve that ?

Comment: Wolframalpha indicates the answer is no (well if you use the general solution formula then yes but I would not say that is computable by human hand). However this does not reject the existence of a possible smart way to directly derive an answer to $S$ without solving the value of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: @user157844 The solution to any cubic equation can be found here:  http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/

Answer (score 1):

**Question**: $\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) = \frac {4}{7}$ and $S=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2{x}}+\dfrac{1}{\cos^2{2x}} + \dfrac{1}{\cos^2{3x}} $ when $ S \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ then $ S = ?$

**Working Out**: let $a = \cos(x)$, $b = \cos(2x)$, $c = \cos(3x)$, then:
$$abc = \frac {4}{7}$$ $$S=\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2} + \dfrac{1}{c^2} $$

Because $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1$, $\therefore b = 2a^2 -1$.

Because $\cos(3x) = \cos(x)\cos(2x) - \sin(x)(2\sin(x)\cos(x)) = ab - 2a\sin^2(x)$.

As $2a\sin^2(x) = 2a(1- \cos^2(x)) = 2a(1-a^2)$

$\therefore \cos(3x) = ab(2a^2-1) - 2a(1-a^2) = 4a^3 - 3a$

$\therefore c = 4a^3 - 3a$

So we get the following equation:
$$a(2a^2 - 1)(4a^3 - 3a) = \frac {4}{7}$$
$$56a^6 - 70a^4 + 21a^2 - 4 = 0$$

As I have know special way of solving such polynomials I turned to wolfram alpha and got an approximate root of $a = -0.96392$ and $a = 0.96392$. But $a = \cos(x)$, so when $a = -0.96292$ $x = 164.562(3.dp)$ and when $a = 0.96392$ $x = 15.4378 (4.dp)$. Putting those values into the equation of $S$, we get:

$$S=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(164.562)}+\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(2 * 164.562)} + \dfrac{1}{\cos^2(3 * 164.562)} $$

$$\therefore S = 10.673$$

Or

$$S=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(15.4378)}+\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(2 * 15.4378)} + \dfrac{1}{\cos^2(3 * 15.4378)} $$

$$\therefore S = 4.54217$$

**Answer**: $$S = 4.54217, S = 10.673$$

Comment: thank you for sharing solution to us. thumbs up!!!