# How to solve the cubic equation $56z^3-70z^2-21z-4=0$?

Tags: cubics

$56z^3-70z^2-21z-4=0$ how to solve for $z$. I formed three equations but not getting the answer. If I get a start or suggestion it would be a great help.

Comment: Is this by any chance motivated by [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585250/if-cosx-cos2x-cos3x-frac47-find-frac1-cos2x-frac)?

Comment: The rational root theorem does not yield any solutions to this. So it will most likely consist of 3 real solutions, or 1 real and 2 complex solutions. Look into the cubic formula, it will give you your solutions.

Comment: The question is almost similar

Comment: is $z$ a real variable?

Comment: I dont have solutions all i want is solutions complex or real

Comment: Did you try Cardano ?

Comment: I saw it but it would be good if someone explained a bit more rather than just giving the site names

Comment: I am not suggesting you to go to the site but to learn the method from the site. You must know how the method works.

Comment: Sorry if i have been rude but im in 11th std to understand  so that is way to far so i asked it here

Comment: I think. You should try synthetic division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a concise formula so anytime you come across a cubic you can easily solve it yourself. Given,

$$Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$$

divide by $A$ to get the simpler,

$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$$

then,

$$x = \frac{1}{3}\left(-a+u_1^{1/3}+\frac{a^2-3b}{u_1^{1/3}}\right)$$

where $u$ is any non-zero root of the quadratic,

$$u^2 + (2 a^3 - 9 a b + 27 c) u + (a^2 - 3 b)^3 = 0$$

**P.S.** This is the formula used by *Mathematica* though simplified for aesthetics.

Comment: Just to add, taking the cube root of a number will give you three solutions $u_1^{1/3} e^{2\pi i k/3}$ for $k=0,1,2$. These will yield the three roots $x_i$ of the cubic.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$56z^3-70z^2-21z-4=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Eliminate the quadratic term by substituting $x=z-\frac{5}{12}$:

---

$$56x^3-\frac{301x}{6}-\frac{563}{27}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^3-\frac{43x}{48}-\frac{563}{1512}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

If $x=y+\frac{\lambda}{y}$ then $y=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-\lambda}\right)$:

---

$$-\frac{563}{1512}-\frac{43}{48}\left(y+\frac{\lambda}{y}\right)+\left(y+\frac{\lambda}{y}\right)^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\lambda=\frac{43}{144}$ and then $u=y^3$, yielding a quadratic equation in the variable $u$:

---

$$u^2-\frac{563u}{1512}+\frac{79507}{2985984}=0$$

Comment: Why is z substituted with $5/12$

Comment: To Eliminate the quadratic term

Comment: But why specifically only $5/12$ please explain

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Because otherwise you don't eliminate the quadratic term

Comment: That's called the Tschirnhaus transformation. The rule is to make the substitution $x=z-\frac{b}{3a}$. To prove this works, make that substitution in a general cubic equation and see how the quadratic term cancels.

Comment: @ Jan Eerland thats what i was asking which is answered by Kristoffer Ryhl.

Comment: Thanks very much Kristoffer  Ryhl

Comment: @ArchisWelankar That was what I ment!

Comment: No you interpreted wrongly i wanted general substitution but still thanks.